# i installed theme but not working home page

Tags: magento2

i installed porto theme. but not working theme. im using magento 2.4.2

`Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $adapters of Magento\Search\Model\AdapterFactory.`

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to ElasticSearch as Magento 2.4 needs elastic search.
Restart your elasticesearch using below command(linux) :

> sudo service elasticsearch restart

If it works fine, then check from modules using below command :

> php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Elasticsearch6
> Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Elasticsearch7

Also check ElasticSearch service in **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search**

Clean all cache.